# How should you initialize constant data that needs parameters from another part of the code?

Tags: c#

I don't think I explained my question very well in the title, so I'll do my best to do it here.

I have an abstract class called `Song`, a class that extends it `MidiSong`and then I have a `SongCreator` interface and a `MidiSongCreator`class that implements it. I would like to have a way to store lots of `SongCreators` so I can call their Create method but the problem is, since the SongCreators will each be a `MidiSongCreator` I am wondering how I should initialize each `MidiSongCreator` since it takes a MIDIPlayer and other things to help initialize it which doesn't have a static reference to it. Should I create a static class that holds lots of SongCreators? Should I not make the SongList class static?

What is looks like:

```
public abstract class Song{
    public IList<Playable> notes { get; private set; }

    public SongPlayData Start(){
         // calls onStartEvent
       return CreateSongData();
    }
    protected abstract SongPlayData CreateSongData();
    public bool Update(SongPlayData songData, float songTime,List<SongPlayer> players) { // note that the players list is a list of people who are playing this game (this is a rhythm game) (doesn't have anything to do with MIDIPlayer

    }
    public void End(){
       //calls end event
    }
}
public class MidiSong : Song { // this is the class that needs the MIDIPlayer parameter

    public MIDIPlayer midiPlayer;

    protected MidiSong(MIDIPlayer player){
        this.midiPlayer = player;
    }

    protected override SongPlayData CreateSongData() {
        return new MidiSongData(midiPlayer);
    }
}
public interface SongCreator<out T> where T : Song {


    T Create();


}
   public class MidiSongCreator : SongCreator<MidiSong>, IListenerObject { // this is the class that I need to store lots of instances of. the midiPlayer will probably be the same every time

    private MIDIPlayer player;

    public MidiSongCreator(MIDIPlayer player) {
        this.player = player;
        Init();
    }


    private void Init() {
        player.midiListener.listener = this;
        // 
    }
    private void Clear() { // resets all the data so we can create another Song if we need to (even without entering stuff in)
        if(player.midiListener.listener == this) {
            player.midiListener.listener = null;
        }
    }



    public MidiSong Create() {



        MidiSong r = new MidiSong(player);
        // I'm still going to implement calls to other methods from midiPlayer
        Clear();
        return r;
    }

    public void OnLoad(MidiFile file) {
        // does stuff to load midi file (deals with individual events)
    }

}
public class MasterSong : MonoBehaviour { // this should initialize last btw (It's in the Script Execution Order)


    public MIDIPlayer midiPlayer;
    public Song song;
    public SongPlayData playData;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start() {
        // this is where I'd like to reference a SongCreator and call it's create method and Start the song
        //for instance:
        song = SongList.SONG_NAME.Create();
        playData = song.Start();
    }

    void Update() {

    }
}
```

It's a RhythmGame made with unity, but I didn't add the unity tag because I feel that this is more of a C#/design thing.

Also note, that I have my classes much more organized that just one file with all these.

I'm looking for ways to improve on the design that I have.

Comment: Can you post some code of what you have so far?  It is easier to visualize with code.

Comment: I didn't like word problems in elementary school and I still don't like them now.  Don't describe your code in words, **post it**

Comment: Fair enough. I'll comment back when I'm done editing it.

Comment: Done editing. I added most of the code that has the deisgn I'm talking about.

Comment: Start method of MasterSong class now sort of explains it. My original question was how I should store lots of different SongCreators but each SongCreator needed to be initialized with MIDIPlayer and I didn't want to add MIDIPlayer as a parameter in SongCreator's Create method.

Comment: Now I get it, I didn't notice full code. For me it looks like `Unity` specific question.

Comment: I don't think so. It could probably be answered by the unity community but all of the classes I posted except MasterSong don't really use the UnityEngine namespace at all. I was trying to ask how I should be storing lots of the SongCreators, a static class, an object. Just wondering what the best choice would be for a design like that since I was unsure of creating an initialize method in the SongList (not shown)

Comment: I see `MasterSong` inherits from `MonoBehavior` which have a lot of stuff inside. I don't know where and when Unity creates instances of these classes. It is Unity specific question. Maybe this will help: https://github.com/modesttree/Zenject

Answer (score 1):

**This is a design problem, domain design!**

I suggest don't write code yet. Create a class diagram, with pen and paper, don't need to use tools in the beginning.

- Try to determine **entities** - classes, interfaces etc - and the **relationship among them**. Just use boxes and arrow, don't need to put details yet. With boxes and arrows, you will be able to have a picture of your domain much more clearly. Keep refining and changing it, still at this high level, without details, until you are satisfied.
- Then, step by step, refine it by adding details/properties such attributes and methods. This may cause to change the diagram from the first step.

I intentionally did not refer to specifics of you questions like the classes and interfaces you mentioned. Since, there is not enough information to comment on that. Secondly, and more importantly, you should start at high level of design and once that is done, then do coding based on your design.